# -1 * int.MinValue == int.MinValue?? Is this a bug?

Tags: c#, .net, integer-overflow

In C# I see that

```
-1 * int.MinValue == int.MinValue
```

Is this a bug?  It really screwed me up when I was trying to implement a search tree.  I ended up using `(int.MinValue + 1)` so that I could properly negate it.

Comment: +1 Very interesting and funny question :D

Comment: This is one of those things I really don't understand, Why is C# unchecked by default?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is not a bug.

`int.MinValue * -1` is `1` greater than `int.MaxValue` can hold.  Thus, the number wraps around back to `int.MinValue`.

This is basically caused by an integer overflow.

[**`Int32.MinValue`:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.minvalue.aspx)

> The value of this constant is `-2,147,483,648`

[**`Int32.MaxValue`:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx)

> The value of this constant is `2,147,483,647`

So, `-2,147,483,648 * -1 = 2,147,483,648` which is `1` greater than `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: integer math is sooo coool! ;)

Comment: @Mark, in this case, I think it is not cool.  It is confusing.

Comment: Depends how you look at it. From a bitwise perspective with `-x := ~x + 1` and `Int32.MinValue` being `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` it's actually quite plausible. And the '32' in `Int32` does point just right to that direction :)

Answer (score 9):

It's not a bug, it's an overflow.

In [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation, the space of representable numbers is not symmetric. The opposite of the smallest integer cannot be represented. Computing it overflows and gives you the same number again.

Comment: for less than a second, I thought you would say It's not a bug, it's an feature. :D

Answer (score 8):

```
int i = -1 * int.MinValue;
```

This doesn't even compile unless you disable checking:

```
error CS0220: The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that checked mode is apparently disabled by default.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't a bug.  It is the nature of twos complement integer arithmetic.

For example, let us take a signed byte value which goes between `-128` and `127`.

`127(0x7f)+1 = 128(0x80)`.  However, `0x80` is in fact the binary representation of `-128`.

Thus, for a byte, `128(0x80) = -128(0x80)`

So `-128(0x80) * -1 = 128(0x80) = -128(0x80)`

Answer (score 2):

Put a checked region on it and see the "bug" evolve into an exception. Or try VB.NET (which as far as I recall is checked by default unlike C#).